# Linear Algebra : Check similarity

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix with complex entries, then $A$ is similar over C to a matrix of one of the two types

$$
          \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             a & 0 \\
             0 & b \\
                \end{array} } \right]  
$$

$$
          \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             a & 0 \\
             1 & a \\
                \end{array} } \right]  
$$

When For $2 \times 2$ matrix $N$ such that $N^{2} = 0$, $N$ is similar to 
$$
          \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             0 & 0 \\
             1 & 0 \\
                \end{array} } \right]  
$$

The source of the problem is  by Hoffman and Kunze.

Comment: Do you mean over complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$? And by that you mean a matrix with entries in $\mathbb{C}$? Could you please show some of your work?

Comment: are you aware of Jordan canonical forms... ??

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What are the eigenvalues of $N$?  There are two cases to consider, depending on how many linearly independent eigenvectors $N$ has.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

As $A\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ , corresponding polynomial $\det(A-xI)$ is a quadratic.

Now, possibilities for roots $r_1,r_2$ of $\det(A-xI)$ are :

- $r_1=r_2\neq 0$
- $r_1\neq r_2$
- $r_1=r_2=0$

Do you see which case implies $N^2=0$???? what would be its corresponding matrix?

Comment: No, My class haven't covered Nilpotency yet. We only covered Determinent function and Characteristic function

Comment: by nilpotency, i mean some positive power of a matrix is zero matrix....